# How to make Prototypejs onComplete fire an alert?

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am using prototype js and scriptaculous sortable but when i do an oncomplete alert or anything, it does not work. The sortable and all the code works well but the onComplete does not work.

Here is mycode

```
<script>
        Event.observe(window,'load',init,false);
        function init() {
            Sortable.create('listContainer',{tag:'div',onUpdate:updateList});
        }
        function updateList(container) {
            var url = 'ajax.php';
            var params = Sortable.serialize(container.id);
            var ajax = new Ajax.Request(url,{
                method: 'post',
                parameters: params,
                onLoading: function(){$('workingMsg').show()},
                onLoaded: function(){$('workingMsg').hide()},

                                 onComplete: function(){ alert('good'); }

 });
        }
        function handleResponse(req) {
            // this function will fire after the ajax request is complete...but we have nothing to do here
        }
    </script>
```

Everything works perfectly when i launch the function except the fact that onComplete the alert is not sent.

**How to make Prototypejs onComplete fire an alert ?**

Comment: Your code looks like ok, but I guess there is something wrong before `onComplete`. You can try `onFailure`  instead of `onComplete`. May you can see `good` in alert.

Comment: @孙悟空 I have tried that yet still it did not work.

Comment: If you remove `onLoading` or `onLoaded` or both of them. Can you see alert ?

Comment: Not it does not fire an alert even when i remove it yet the script works